# Node JS Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have been struggling around to have socket.io npm module setup and that my browser be able to interface with back end NodeJS script. But I am not sure where am I going wrong. I remeber seeing previously messages in console that:

**"Socket.io .. started .."**

But nothing happens now. Below is my NodeJS code:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = require('http').createServer(express);
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
global.socket = require('socket.io')(server);
//global.socket = require('socket.io').listen(80, {log:true});
//socket.listen(80, {log:true});
```

In my index.js file I have a function that catches socket.io incoming connections. When I try the below URL from browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

I get a error message:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\amr\public" at Function.app.render
```

But when I request below URL:

```
http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

It seems that socket.io.js file is rendered on the browser:

```
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{var f;"undefined"!=typeof window?f=window:"undefined"!=typeof global?f=global:"undefined"!=typeof self&&(f=self),f.io=e()}}(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){
```

I am not sure how from browser or backend side I can see if my web socket is working, what is the script URL i have to include in my HTML page such that the connection works?

```
<script src="http://localhost:80/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have exposed the socket.io client-side library to the public. If you used the express generator, just copy and paste that file to `yourproject/public` and send your requests to `localhost:3000/<insert socket.io clientside filename>`

If you didn't use the express generator, make a folder called public, and then in your main project file place the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and then do what I described above

Oh, and your error there refers to the view engine not being able to find the view for error printing. Fix that and it'll give you more info.